# TFS2018 package step and include files

Tags: tfs, octopus-deploy

I am using Octopus for the Package Application step in the build procedure. Under Advanced options I specify /bin/*.dll for include files. However the build doesn't pick up the files. If I leave the include empty it picks up all the files. Is the syntax not valid like this

> /bin/*.dll

I also tried

> bin/*.dll

but without luck. Any idea what might be wrong?

Here is a screenshot of the build steps...

[image]

Here is the log for the Octopus package step

> 2017-12-02T17:28:15.4090188Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step:
>   'Package MyProject' 2017-12-02T17:28:15.4090955Z ##[debug]Evaluating:
>   succeeded() 2017-12-02T17:28:15.4091343Z ##[debug]Evaluating
>   succeeded: 2017-12-02T17:28:15.4092307Z ##[debug]=> (Boolean) True
>   2017-12-02T17:28:15.4093048Z ##[debug]Expanded: True
>   2017-12-02T17:28:15.4093619Z ##[debug]Result: True
>   2017-12-02T17:28:15.4095310Z ##[section]Starting: Package MyProject
>   2017-12-02T17:28:15.4101223Z
>   ============================================================================== 2017-12-02T17:28:15.4101741Z Task         : Package Application
>   2017-12-02T17:28:15.4102147Z Description  : Package your application
>   into a NuPkg or Zip file. 2017-12-02T17:28:15.4102500Z Version      :
>   2.0.78 2017-12-02T17:28:15.4102834Z Author       : Octopus Deploy 2017-12-02T17:28:15.4103263Z Help         : Version: 2.0.78. [More
>   Information](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Use+the+Team+Foundation+Build+Custom+Task)
>   2017-12-02T17:28:15.4103847Z
>   ============================================================================== 2017-12-02T17:28:15.4115642Z ##[debug]tf vc resolvePath
>   $\MyParentFolder\MyProject\MyProject /loginType:OAuth
>   /login:.,******** /noprompt 2017-12-02T17:28:15.8042302Z
>
> ### [debug]C:\a\w\2\s\MyParentFolder\MyProject\MyProject 2017-12-02T17:28:16.8462262Z ##[debug]VstsTaskSdk 0.6.4 commit
>
> a074a158dbd70b5a72d1295ee42684c30a262b19 2017-12-02T17:28:16.9168209Z
>
> ### [debug]Entering C:\a\w_tasks\OctopusPack_179fac12-2402-486e-80cf-5a6a8571f7c0\2.0.78\Octopus-Pack.ps1.
>
> 2017-12-02T17:28:16.9521027Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_PACKAGEID: 'MyProject'
>   2017-12-02T17:28:16.9547735Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_PACKAGEFORMAT: 'NuPkg'
>   2017-12-02T17:28:16.9596389Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_PACKAGEVERSION:
>   '20171202.3' 2017-12-02T17:28:16.9645182Z
>
> ### [debug]Env:INPUT_OUTPUTPATH: 'C:\a\w\2\a' 2017-12-02T17:28:16.9645553Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_SOURCEPATH:
>
> 'C:\a\w\2\s\MyParentFolder\MyProject\MyProject'
>   2017-12-02T17:28:16.9651385Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_NUGETAUTHOR: 'MyBrand'
>   2017-12-02T17:28:16.9699352Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_NUGETTITLE:
>   'MyParentFolder.B2BAccounts' 2017-12-02T17:28:16.9715752Z
>
> ### [debug]Env:INPUT_NUGETDESCRIPTION: 'My service' 2017-12-02T17:28:16.9729595Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_NUGETRELEASENOTES
>
> (empty) 2017-12-02T17:28:16.9786830Z
>
> ### [debug]Env:INPUT_NUGETRELEASENOTESFILE: 'C:\a\w\2\s' 2017-12-02T17:28:16.9812364Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_OVERWRITE: 'false'
>
> 2017-12-02T17:28:16.9843490Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
>   2017-12-02T17:28:16.9868739Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_INCLUDE: './bin/*.dll'
>   2017-12-02T17:28:16.9896116Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_LISTFILES: 'false'
>   2017-12-02T17:28:16.9914671Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
>   2017-12-02T17:28:16.9947636Z No Release notes file found
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.0153048Z ##[debug]Entering Invoke-VstsTool.
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.0269801Z ##[debug] FileName:
>   'C:\a\w_tasks\OctopusPack_179fac12-2402-486e-80cf-5a6a8571f7c0\2.0.78\Octo.exe'
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.0289645Z ##[debug] Arguments: 'pack
>   --id="MyProject" --format=NuPkg --version=20171202.3 --outFolder="C:\a\w\2\a" --basePath="C:\a\w\2\s\MyParentFolder\MyProject\MyProject" --author="RB" --title="MyParentFolder.B2BAccounts" --description="My service" --releaseNotes=""  --overwrite=False --include="./bin/*.dll"'
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.0336805Z ##[debug] RequireExitCodeZero: 'True'
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.0375950Z
>
> ### [command]"C:\a\w_tasks\OctopusPack_179fac12-2402-486e-80cf-5a6a8571f7c0\2.0.78\Octo.exe"
>
> pack --id="MyProject" --format=NuPkg --version=20171202.3
>   --outFolder="C:\a\w\2\a" --basePath="C:\a\w\2\s\MyParentFolder\MyProject\MyProject" --author="RB" --title="MyParentFolder.B2BAccounts" --description="My service" --releaseNotes=""  --overwrite=False --include="./bin/*.dll"
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.1287470Z Octopus Deploy Command Line Tool, version
>   4.22.1 2017-12-02T17:28:17.1294636Z  2017-12-02T17:28:17.3764140Z Packing MyProject version "20171202.3"... 2017-12-02T17:28:17.3926084Z
>   Saving "MyProject.20171202.3.nupkg" to "C:\a\w\2\a"...
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.4063617Z  2017-12-02T17:28:17.4063997Z
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a package that has no
>   dependencies nor content. 2017-12-02T17:28:17.4064229Z    at
>   NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder.Save(Stream stream)
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.4064537Z    at
>   Octopus.Cli.Commands.NuGetPackageBuilder.BuildPackage(String basePath,
>   IList`1 includes, ManifestMetadata metadata, String outFolder, Boolean
>   overwrite, Boolean verboseInfo) 2017-12-02T17:28:17.4064836Z    at
>   Octopus.Cli.Commands.PackCommand.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0()
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.4065077Z    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke() 2017-12-02T17:28:17.4065264Z
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() 2017-12-02T17:28:17.4065487Z
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 2017-12-02T17:28:17.4065866Z    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) 2017-12-02T17:28:17.4066304Z    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) 2017-12-02T17:28:17.4066598Z    at
>   Octopus.Cli.Program.Run(String[] args) 2017-12-02T17:28:17.4067897Z
>   Exit code: -3 2017-12-02T17:28:17.4164951Z ##[debug]Exit code: -3
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.4309447Z ##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.4341893Z ##[debug]Leaving
>   C:\a\w_tasks\OctopusPack_179fac12-2402-486e-80cf-5a6a8571f7c0\2.0.78\Octopus-Pack.ps1.
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.4387076Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task
>   script. 2017-12-02T17:28:17.4420714Z ##[debug]Error record:
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.5138233Z ##[debug]Invoke-VstsTool : Process
>   'Octo.exe' exited with code '-3'. 2017-12-02T17:28:17.5149782Z
>
> ### [debug]At C:\a\w_tasks\OctopusPack_179fac12-2402-486e-80cf-5a6a8571f7c0\2.0.78\Octopus-Pack.ps1:52
>
> char:5 2017-12-02T17:28:17.5163924Z ##[debug]+     Invoke-VstsTool
>   -FileName $octoPath -Arguments $Arguments -Requir ... 2017-12-02T17:28:17.5176209Z ##[debug]+
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.5189971Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          :
>   NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.5202114Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-VstsTool
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.6236509Z ##[debug]  2017-12-02T17:28:17.6456023Z
>
> ### [debug]Script stack trace: 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6456411Z ##[debug]at Invoke-Tool,
>
> C:\a\w_tasks\OctopusPack_179fac12-2402-486e-80cf-5a6a8571f7c0\2.0.78\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\ToolFunctions.ps1:
>   line 86 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6456866Z ##[debug]at ,
>   C:\a\w_tasks\OctopusPack_179fac12-2402-486e-80cf-5a6a8571f7c0\2.0.78\Octopus-Pack.ps1:
>   line 52 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6457192Z ##[debug]at , : line 1 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6457473Z ##[debug]at ,
>   : line 22 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6457737Z ##[debug]at
>   , : line 18 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6458018Z
>
> ### [debug]at , : line 1 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6458303Z ##[debug]Exception:
>
> 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6458589Z
>
> ### [debug]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Process 'Octo.exe' exited with code '-3'. 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6637507Z
>
> ### [error]Process 'Octo.exe' exited with code '-3'. 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6637766Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue
>
> type=error]Process 'Octo.exe' exited with code '-3'.
>   2017-12-02T17:28:17.6644964Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete
>   result=Failed] 2017-12-02T17:28:17.6965505Z ##[section]Finishing:
>   Package MyProject

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the problem is happening before the package reaches Octopus, is that correct?

Comment: Hi @ChrisB.Behrens yes, well the package step is part of Octopus as you see in the screenshot .The blue box indicates what files are being included.

Comment: Yeah, but my point is that your problem is that the package is not being built properly, which is happening long before Octopus is involved, so this isn't really an Octopus question.

Comment: I suspect that your build path don't match up with where the build is looking. Try ./bin/*.dll instead.

Comment: Hi @ChrisB.Behrens thanks for your quick reply. I tried ./bin/* but the same problem occurs it doesn´t pick up the files in the folder. The bulid step before the octopus package step is actually building successfully and I can see the files in the project folder on the build agent server. s\MyParentFolder\MyProject\ If I specify e.g. /*.config in the include field it actually picks up config files located inside MyProject. But this doesn´t work if I specify subfolders. Unless I leave the include field empty but then all files are picked up which I don´t want.

Comment: What do you get with the include? An empty package?

Comment: Yes, thats right. The error message says System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content.

Comment: Ah, I can see now why your tagging Octopus, it's an Octopack step.

Comment: :) yes, thats right! Do you know if this is a bug?

Comment: I reviewed the docs here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octopusdeploy.octopus-deploy-build-release-tasks. Pretty sparse coverage for that include option. Can you post the log output of that step? Maybe that will give us a clue.

Comment: I added the log output...

Comment: Okay, so the effective path for the dll's is C:\a\w\2\s\MyParentFolder\MyProject\MyProject\bin\*.dll. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160380/discussion-between-chris-b-behrens-and-doorman).

Comment: Hi @ChrisB.Behrens thanks again for your help. I got a reply from the Octopus team and the trick was to use a pattern like ** /bin/*.dll. The double star will match any number of preceding folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick was to use a pattern like ** /bin/*.dll. The double star will match any number of preceding folders.